# If A is open in the Borel $\sigma$ alg. is it open in the original Topology?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Here is what I have:
$(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space, and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma-$algebra corresponding to the topology $\mathcal{T}$.

By definition $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest $\sigma-$algebra containing all open sets.( So if $A_1$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$ then it is open in $\mathcal{B}$...correct?)

My real question is if I take any arbitrary $A_2$ that is open in the $\sigma-$algebra ($A_2\in \mathcal{B}$) then is it open in original the topology? So is $A_2\in\mathcal{T}$?

Comment: What do you mean by « open in the $\sigma$ algebra »? The notion of openness is a topological one, not a measure-theoretic one. An open set in B has to be open according to some topology, and if it is according to the one that generates the Borel algebra, it is of course open in the topology . However there are many sets that are in the Borel sigma algebra, but are not open. (For instance, any closed set that is not open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology $\mathfrak{T}$ and let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $\mathfrak{T}$. Then, the closed interval $[0,1]$ belongs to $\mathcal{B}$ (its complement is an open set and $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under complements), but $[0,1]$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. That is, $[0,1] \notin \mathfrak{T}$.

The issue here is that topologies are not usually $\sigma$-algebras (and $\sigma$-algebras are not always topologies)! More importantly, topologies need not be closed under complements. It is for this reason that is dangerous to use the terminology "$A$ is open in $\mathcal{B}$" to say that $A \in \mathcal{B}$.

Fundamentally, topologies and $\sigma$-algebras are very different structures. We typically only discuss openness relative to a topology, and it does not make much sense to say that a set is open relative to an algebra. Here are some important distinctions between $\sigma$-algebras an topologies:

- $\sigma$-algebras are only closed under *countable* unions; a topology must be closed with respect to *arbitrary* (even uncountable) unions.
- $\sigma$-algebras must be closed relative to complements. On the other hand, topologies need not satisfy this property.
- Topologies are closed under *finitely many* intersections. However, $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countably many intersections!

Nonetheless, because $\mathcal{B}$ must always contain the original topology $\mathcal{T}$, it **is** true that $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$.